# Highlight Background of Text based on Status Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have to display status with background color like below.

Below image is from Web Panel and i have to do this in my flutter app.

[image]

if status have **Unassigned** then color is **purple**, if status have **Resolved** then color is **Green**, if status have **Closed** then color is **Red**.

Below Code which Displays Status.

```
List<TicketModel> arrayList = [];

Row(
                    children: [
                      Text("Status",
                          style:
                              Themes.getPlanCellTitleLabelTextStyle(context)),
                      Spacer(),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "${arrayList[index].status}",
                            style: Themes.getTextStyleBoldBlack(context),
                          ),
                          
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) widget with some padding and a ternary expression to determine the color of the box (if there are more possibilities than "Unassigned", "Resolved" and "Closed", consider making a function that would return the correct color).

An example code that would replace your [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget:

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: arrayList[index].status == 'Unassigned'
      ? Colors.purple
      : arrayList[index].status == 'Resolved'
        ? Colors.green
        : Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 8,
    vertical: 3,
  ),
  child: Text(arrayList[index].status),
)
```

Of course you can still tweak the colors, text styling, etc.

Comment: Works Perfectly.. Thank You So Much....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to get Color based on text.

```dart
  Color _bgColor(String status) {
    switch (status) {
      case "Unassigned":
        return Colors.purple;
      case "Resolved":
        return Colors.green;
      case "Closed":
        return Colors.red;
      default:
        return Colors.transparent; // for unknwon
    }
  }
```

And wrap the `Text` Widget with `Container` and provide color.

```dart
       Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _bgColor(status),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Text(
              status,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), // set your style here
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the result by making a List of Map of status and their colors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> status = [
    {"status" : "Unassigned", "color" : Colors.purple},
    {"status" : "Resolved", "color" : Colors.green},
    {"status" : "Closed", "color" : Colors.red}
  ];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: status.asMap().map((index, value) => MapEntry(index,Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 5),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        color: status[index]["color"],
        child:Text("${status[index]["status"]}")))).values.toList(),
    );
  }
}
```